# How can I delete only a certain group from the links using regular expressions in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a lot of files and they have something like this text:

```
<a class=“table-row” href=“value1/value2”>
. . .
<a class=“table-row” href=“value3/value4">
. . .
```

How to delete first groups following the href and the slash, using regexp in Notepad++, so that eventually the links look like this:

```
<a class=“table-row“ href=”value2“>

<a class=”table-row“ href="value4">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex `(href=")(\w+\/)` and replace for `$1`.

In Notepad++ you can type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and in "Replace" tab set like this:

[image]

Then click `Replace All` and all ocurrences will be removed.

Comment: No needs to escape the slash and group 2 is superfluous because you don't use it in the replacement. Also this will not work for `href=“value-1/value2”`